# Set X.Value by variable

Tags: excel, vba, initialization, excel-charts

I have the following X-coordinate that I store as PAR_09 (and y-coordinate as PAR_10):

```
Dim PAR_09 As String 
PAR_09 = Sheets("Sensor").Cells(i, 4).Value
Sheets("template").ChartObjects("planview").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
            .Name = "Point"
            .XValues = "={" & PAR_09 & "}"
            .Values = "={" & PAR_10 & "}"
End With
```

Now the x-coordinate = 230,9 in which , is a decimal seperator. Due to my code, the Xseries in my chart stored this coordinate as {230\9} and therefore it actually plots 230 and 9 separately as two x-coordinates. How can I avoid this? 
I tried declaring PAR_09 as a Double - didn't work.

Comment: `Replace` the `,` with `.`?

Comment: If you just have one value in that range, then `.XValues = Sheets("Sensor").Cells(i, 4).Value`.

Comment: I could, but in the end this part of the code needs to be repeated for a big dataset in which all the data is indicated with a , as decimal seperator..

Comment: VBA is En-US centric so if you're going the way of creating a `String` for `XValues`, you probably need to `Replace` (as in the VBA function) the `,` with `.`. But I would just use a `Range` object.

Comment: Yes I thought so already. I will try some of your suggestions.Thank you!